# React: Render inner component and image together

Tags: reactjs, concurrency, rendering, lazy-loading

I am using a `MainLayout` component to render an image and 1 of 2 other components beside it something like this:

```
<img src="/image.jpg" className={style.image} alt="Enalo" />
<div className={style.child}>{children}</div>
```

Right now the image loads first and then the `children` loads later, I want them both to be rendered together. How should I go about this? Thank you.

Edit: I should also mention that I am destructuring `children` from the props passed to `Main`. The children are coming as props like so:

```
<MainLayout>
   <ChildComponent/>
</MainLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was add the image to both the inner components separately, I know this isn't might not be the optimal solution but rather a workaround, but this is how I had to solve the issue.